# Как вызвать обобщенный метод в данном случае

Tags: c#, .net, generics

У меня имеется generic метода:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Method1<T>()
   where T : Test // какой-то базовый класс
{ ... }

public IEnumerable<T> Method2<T>()
   where T : Test, ISomeInterface // тот же базовый класс + интерфейс
{ ... }
```

мне необходимо вызвать один из них в зависимости от Т, хочется написать что-то типо этого:

```
public IEnumerable<T> MainMethod<T>()
   where T : Test
{
    if (T is ISomeInterface) // как правильно написать этот момент?
        return Method2<T>(); 
    else 
        return Method1<T>();
}
```

В общем, каким образом мне вызвать второй метод, не прибегая к рефлексии?

Comment: А сейчас что, не компилится?

Comment: @aepot я не могу использовать T в выражении (T is ISomeInterface)

Comment: Во, [нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4963190/12888024)

Comment: @aepot , параметров нет, только дженерик. Внутри метод1 и метод2 будет создана нужная мне коллекция. По ссылке - я видел это, все равно вызвать метод2 таким образом не получится из-за типизации

Comment: Тогда только рефлексия, на сдается мне, что вы перемудрили с наследованием в дженериках, и вам стоит подумать, а все ли единственным правильным способом сделано, или можно проще.

Comment: @aepot , всегда, когда доходит до рефлексии, приходит понимание, что что-то не так) но я все же надеялся, что есть адекватный способ это реализовать

Comment: Приведите _компилирующийся_ код ваших методов (без `MainMethod`). Пусть класс `Test` и интерфейс `ISomeInterface` будут пустыми, без членов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov от проблемы избавился другим способом. В моем случае было возможно заменить `ISomeInterface` на еще один абстрактный класс, наследуемый от базового. Дальше воспользовался ковариантностью `IEnumerable`.
Приведенный в вопросе код - очень сильное упрощение реального, оригинал скидывать смысла нет.
В любом случае, спасибо, что хотели помочь

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        return Method2<T>(); 
    else 
        return Method1<T>();
```

По-другому - никак, либо менять условие задачи и передавать в метод объект данного класса, который должен быть не null. То, что вы хотите - это именно задача рефлексии, и она в данном случае - даже более надёжна.